# Instance member getUrl can't be accessed using static access

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use a cloud function that I built on GCP as follows. The objective is to obtain a JSON containing timestamps, images and sources, which will be converted to a Map object. SourceController, datetime and _imageUrl are the outputs, the input is supposed to be the url function parameter:

```
 parser(String url) async {
    var function_url = <CLOUD FUNCTION URL>;
    try {
      var request = await HttpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(function_url));
      var response = await request.close();
      if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
        var json = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
        Map data = jsonDecode(json) as Map;
        sourceController = data['source'];
        publishedAt = data['datetime'];
        _imageUrl = data['image'];
      } else {
         print('Error running parser:\nHttp status ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (exception) {
      print('Failed invoking the parser function.');
    }
```

I keep getting the following error, in spite of changing the data type of request to dynamic, var, etc.

```
Instance member 'getUrl' can't be accessed using static access
```

I would really appreciate some help on why the getUrl does not work, although I've checked other codes where it works alright.

Also, I don't understand where do we pass our arguments to our cloud function if at all?

Also, if there is a solution involving the cloud_functions package, I'm fine with that too - I tried that method too but had not luck there either.

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-io/HttpClient-class.html), you need to *instantiate* the `HttpClient` in order to access that method as it is not a static method:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.getUrl(Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/"))
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and the getUrl error is gone, but it's still not working. Honestly I don't understand the input-output scheme happening here. Where do I pass the input and use it at all within this syntax? Which transform function should I use, since I think join() clearly isn't working?

Comment: @LuckyStrike Looks pretty clear on how to do that. If you have trouble implementing that than that is another question though.

Comment: If so, would appreciate how to go about it.